# Laravel : Error messaging not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello friends I have a form when i enter correct value and pressing submit button i am getting success message

if i am entering wrong value then 
**i am not getting error message please suugest something**

**Controller**

```
  if($getHours <= 16)
    {
        DB::table('labors')->insert($labors_data);
        session::flash('status', 'Labor Timesheet Added Successfully');
        return Redirect:: to('ViewLaborD2S');
    }
    else
    {

        session::flash('status', 'You have entered More than 16 Hours');
        return Redirect:: to('ViewLaborD2S');

    }
```

**View**

```
    @if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p style="text-align:center;">{{ session('status') }}</p>
        </div>
    @else(session('message'))
       <div class="alert alert-danger">
           <p style="text-align:center;">{{ session('message') }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif
```

I want to show Success message if i entered correct value 
and if i enter wrong value show error message

Comment: I suggest you to make your problem more clear. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: Now it make sense @CharlotteDunois

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@if (Session::has('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p style="text-align:center;">{{ Session::pull('status') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Not working I have updated my code please check above sorry for delay..